# Delete the GNU GRUB from my computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I just uninstalled my Ubuntu partitions and have a problem to delete the GNU GRUB from my computer.

I worked with the [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) guide but cant finish the "Fix the Windows Boot Loader" stage.

After I restarted my computer and opened the windows installer and typed:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

I restarted the computer and got a black screen with the title: GNU GRUB version 2.02 and text:

> Minimal BASH-like line editing is
>   supported. For the first word, Tab lists possible command completions.
>   Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

I opened linux through my disk-on-key and tried to figure out from where the GNU GRUB came from and I figured that I have alot of partitions:
[partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZpaJ.jpg)

This time, I changed my BIOS settings and set windows to be the default boot. How can I remove the GNU GRUB from my computer and check if I have another Ubuntu partition on my hardware?
(Also, I see that 2 of the partitions on my laptop are from Lenovo)

Comment: What do you mean by "cant finish the "Fix the Windows Boot Loader" stage"? Why not? What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: If UEFI which yours is, you have to use efibootmgr to delete UEFI entries & manually delete the /EFI/ubuntu folder in the ESP - efi system partition. Details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: I tried to remove by mount:
"sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/efipart
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command."

Answer (score 1):

you have to run both:

```
 bootrec.exe /fixboot
 bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

An then restart

Comment: Still the same black screen: GNU GRUB version 2.02

Answer (score 0):

From windows you can try EasyBCD software to remove the linux boot option.
In there you can use the "Edit Boot Menu" remove the grub

Comment: http://i.cubeupload.com/NNG2ON.png Cant find GNU GRUB there.